# For discrete $X, Z$, how to show $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \sum_{z \in Z}\mathbb{E}[Y|X, Z=z]\mathbb{P}[Z=z|X]$ if $\mathbb{E}$ is the simple average?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that we have discrete random variables $X, Z$, with $Y$ being possibly continuous. I am wondering if the following formula is valid and how to obtain it:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] = \sum_{z \in Z}\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X, Z=z\right]\mathbb{P}\left[Z=z|X\right]
$$

**The expectation here is assumed to be the finite sample simple average**.

As an example, suppose $X \in \{0,1\}$. Then, to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X = 1\right]$, I would take all the values of $Y$ at level $X = 1$, such as $Y(X = 1)$, and average them.

For the proof, I start with:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] = \sum_{y \in Y}y\cdot \mathbb{P}\left[Y=y|X, Z=z\right]
$$

Then I perform Bayes Rule on $\mathbb{P}\left[Y=y|X, Z=z\right]$ to get the final equation above.

**HOWEVER**, if the expectation is the the simple average, doesn't that mean instead of having:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] = \sum_{y \in Y}y\cdot \mathbb{P}\left[Y=y|X, Z=z\right]
$$

I would be instead left with:

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] = \frac{1}{|Y_x|}\sum_{y \in Y}y
$$

where $|Y_x|$ is the number of occurrences of $Y$ under a setting of $X$?

How can I reconcile these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expectation is *not* a "simple average", rather it *is* a "weighted average", and that "weight" is the probability measure.

Comment: So are you saying the above formula $\mathbb{E}\left[Y|X\right] = \sum_{y \in Y}y\cdot \mathbb{P}\left[Y=y|X, Z=z\right]$ holds correctly?

Comment: No, the formula is $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=\sum_{y\in Y} y\cdot\mathbb P(Y=y\mid X)$ if $Y$ is discrete, of $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=\int_{y\in Y} y\cdot f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid X)\mathsf d y$ if absolutely continuous.

Comment: I see, in a problem I have, my $P(Y=y\mid X)$ are simple count proportions (such as tallying empirical data). Would that admit a valid expectation?